# Nginx not passing response body from Server 1 to Server 2 when 401 status code with new access token is returned

Tags: reactjs, node.js, django, docker, nginx

**Question:**

I'm currently working on a ReactJS application that interacts with multiple backends, including an authentication server using Node.js, another backend using Node.js, and a Django server. Nginx is used to manage requests and distribute them between the front end and these backends.

The problem I'm facing arises when I call a backend with an expired access token. In such cases, the authentication server regenerates a new access token and sends it back to the front end. The front end should then make a new request to the same API with this new access token.

The challenge lies in how Nginx handles the response from Server 1 (authentication with Node.js) when it is called indirectly from Server 2 (Django). When Server 1 returns a 401 status code along with a new access token in the response body, Nginx doesn't pass this response body to Server 2 or, subsequently, to the frontend.

Here's a detailed breakdown of the scenario that doesn't work as expected:

**Scenario 1 (Problematic):** Frontend call to Server 2 (Django) via Nginx, but it has to pass through Server 1 (authentication with Node.js) to check the access token first:

1. Front end calls Server 2 via NGINX.
2. NGINX redirects to Server 1.
3. Server 1 returns a failure response with a new access token in the body and a 401 status.
4. Nginx receives the response from Server 1 and returns a 401 status to the frontend, but without the new access token in the body.
5. The frontend receives the response from Nginx as a 401 and checks if it has the new access token in its body to make a new call with the updated token.

The problem is that Nginx doesn't send the body with the new access token.

**Scenario 2 (Working):** If the frontend calls Server 1 directly via Nginx to check the access (for example after a refresh):

1. Frontend calls Server 1 via Nginx.
2. Nginx redirects to Server 1 with the requested data.
3. If the token is valid, Server 1 returns success with a 200 status. Otherwise, it returns failure with a 401 status and includes a new access token in the response body.
4. The frontend gets the response, keeps the session open if it's successful, or makes a new API call with the new access token sent by the first call if it's a failure.

**The Question:**

How can I resolve the issue where Nginx is not passing the response body from Server 1 to Server 2, and subsequently to the frontend when Server 1 returns a 401 status code along with a new access token in the response body, as described in "Scenario 1 (Problematic)"? Is there a specific Nginx configuration or any other solution that can ensure that the response body with the new access token is passed along in this scenario?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

This is the an example on the implementation of backend server on default.conf file:

```
location /backend/ {
    client_max_body_size 2000M;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 6000;
    proxy_read_timeout 6000;
    send_timeout 6000;

    # Use auth_request to send the request to Server 1 for authentication
    auth_request /auth;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    # Capture the response body from Server 1
    auth_request_set $auth_response_body $upstream_http_auth_response_body;

    # Pass the response body to Server 2, along with other headers
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorri_x_user_refresh_token;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Continue to Server 2
    proxy_pass http://my-backend/;
}
```